# Negative -log likelkhood loss when training Normalizing Flow

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, statistics

I am using [nflows](https://github.com/bayesiains/nflows) library to try an train a flow. However, I am getting negative loss values when training. That being said, the loss graph as a whole kinda looks like a normal loss graph (minus the values). And the flow does seem to produce a somewhat standard-normal distribution, which makes me think I am actually training the flow successfully.

[image]

I attached a code snippet of the initialization and the training:

```py
from nflows import transforms, distributions, flows

class NormalizedFlowModel:
    def __init__(self, n_flows, pretrained_path=None, device='cpu', **kwargs):
        self.n_flows = n_flows
        self.net = ResnetAdapter(pretrained_path, device)

        self.latent_dim = kwargs.get('latent_dim', 512)
        self.device = device

        self.transform = transforms.CompositeTransform([
            transforms.MaskedAffineAutoregressiveTransform(features=self.latent_dim, hidden_features=2 * self.latent_dim),
            transforms.RandomPermutation(features=self.latent_dim)
        ] * n_flows)

        # Set target and q0
        base_distribution = distributions.StandardNormal(shape=[self.latent_dim])

        # Construct flow model
        self.flow = flows.Flow(transform=self.transform, distribution=base_distribution)
        self.flow.to(device)

    def train(self, nf_train_loader, **kwargs):
        n_epochs = kwargs.get('n_epochs', 5)
        lr = kwargs.get('lr', 1e-4)
        weight_decay = kwargs.get('weight_decay', 1e-5)

        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.flow.parameters(), lr=lr, weight_decay=weight_decay)
        loss_list = []

        for epoch in tqdm(range(n_epochs), desc="epoch"):

            self.flow.train()
            self.net.eval()

            for batch_idx, (X, Y) in enumerate(nf_train_loader):
                batch_size = X.shape[0]

                X = X.to(self.device)

                with torch.no_grad():
                    outputs, _, latent = self.net(X)

                loss = -self.flow.log_prob(inputs=latent[-1]).mean()
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()

                loss_list.append(loss.item())

        return loss_list
```

We are using the feature map before the FC layer of pretrained resnet as inputs (that is `latent[-1]`).

Why am i getting a negative loss value? and how can i fix that?